# After I create my tables using SQLAlchemy, how can I add additional columns to it?

Tags: mysql, database, orm, sqlalchemy

This is my file so far:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import Table, Text

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:ababab@localhost/alctest',
            echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    fullname = Column(String(100))
    password = Column(String(100))
    addresses = relationship("Address", order_by="Address.id", backref="user")

    def __init__(self, name, fullname, password):
        self.name = name
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    email_address = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

    #foreign key, must define relationship
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship("User", backref = backref('addresses',order_by=id))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This file is pretty simple. It creates a User and Address tables.  After I run this file, the tables are created.

But now I want to add a column to "User". How can I do that? What do I have to do?

Comment: Do you want to add column without changing the existing code?

Comment: @lafada I don't know. I just want to add columns to it.

Comment: Then you best way is sqlalchemy-migrate :).

Answer (score 8):

You can add column with [Table.append_column](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.append_column) method.

```
test = Column('test', Integer)
User.__table__.append_column(test)
```

But this will not fire the `ALTER TABLE` command to add that column in database. As per doc given for `append_column` that command you have to run manually after adding that column in model.

Comment: For certain parts of ORM, in addition to invoking  `__table__.append_column` you also need set `User.__mapper__.add_property('test', test)` - just like it's done in SQLAlchemy [source](https://github.com/ContextLogic/sqlalchemy/blob/fa4b23ed267c36cba4ec562b02042cbc47ac2f9f/ext/declarative.py#L1281)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **You cannot**: AFAIK, currently there is no way to do it from `sqlalchemy` directly.

Howerever, you can use [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://readthedocs.org/docs/sqlalchemy-migrate/en/v0.7.2/versioning.html#modifying-existing-tables) for this if you change your model frequently and have different versions rolled out to production. Else it might be an overkill and you may be better off generating the `ALTER TABLE ...` scripts manually.